# Updating django application, migrations

Tags: python, django, migration, django-south

Is it possible to remove schemamigrations from the Queue? For example. When I run the command ./manage.py migrate --list, it returns a list of all migrations including items that have yet to be migrated.

I have 5 items that have not been migrated yet, but I do not want to migrate 2 of them because I know they will throw an error.

Is is possible to remove those migrations from the 'queue' so to speak?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are they there at all, if you know that will cause an error?

Comment: A previous Developer made the changes directly against the server. After I was satisfied with the changes I made locally I committed to the appropriate branch, pulled onto the server and ran the migrate --list command and noticed the two files added before my changes. They are "out of sequence" with my changes and therefore will cause an error when I try to migrate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the corresponding files from `yourapp/migrations`. There are all files stored after you called

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

These files are named like `0001_initial.py`.

If there is no file, nothing happens when you call

```
python manage.py migrate
```

When your model is ready, you can create new migrations for your database.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`--fake`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-option---fake) option when you run `migrate` to mark those migrations as applied.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I thought about using this! I'm still learning, but from what I understand, wouldn't I or the developer have to pass --fake every time after as well? Would my application churn out an error if I didn't use --fake in all my migrations after?  Thanks for your help and insight!